# How do I get  spell checking to work in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, spellcheck

Typing `adsfsadf` on this edit box now... and there is no spell checking. But in the context menu spell checking is activated, and the correct language is selected. The same issue exists on about 90% of the sites I visit.

How do I get it to work? Is there any another spell checking system for Google Chrome?

UPDATED:

Spell schecking works only for Russian. All settings are English (global system settings and on context menu).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has its own built-in spell checking - which I consider more correct when spell checking multiple languages in the same document (I specifically use English and German).

You can enable it in:
 **Chrome Preferences → Show advanced settings... → Privacy → Use a web service to help resolve spelling errors**

Comment: Thanks, but spell checking works only for 1 random language and all language settings are ignored. Can't change language for spell checking at all:(

Comment: @Altaveron When I type the following sentences in the same box - one in English, one in German - with the last word being wrong in each case, Chrome does offer me the correct spell check: `You're not cool unless you pee in your pannts.` (Chrome: pants)

`Du bist nicht cool, solange du dir nicht in die Hose machsst.` (Chrome: machst)

Comment: This is very bad. But I just want to change spell checking to the second language for full text and can't do it. Auto select and manual language select don't work both.